# Use Swift to interact with an Objective C method that expects a block as an argument

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to write some Swift code that calls an existing Objective C function.  The Objective C function looks like:

```
+(void) getCurrentUserprofileWithCompletion:(RequestCallback)completion {...}
```

where RequestCallback is defined in a .h file as:

```
typedef void (^RequestCallback) (ResponseInfo *responseInfo);
```

I have tried a number of different things, but nothing seems to work.  The code that looks the most logical to me is:

```
let callback: (responseInfo: ResponseInfo) -> Void = {(responseInfo: ResponseInfo) -> Void in
    if let organization: Organizations = Organizations.organizationWithId(orgId) {
        completionBlock(false, nil)
    } else {
        self.switchOrganization(user, organization: organization, completionBlock: completionBlock)
    }
}
Users.getCurrentUserprofileWithCompletion(callback)
```

but this is getting the error

> cannot convert value of type '(responseInfo: ResponseInfo) -> Void' to expected argument type 'RequestCallback!'

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here?  I have scoured the internet looking for help including the various Apple documentation, but either I am blind or misreading because nothing seems to be working.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the type specification for responseInfo a use the type RequestCallback

```
let callback: RequestCallback = { responseInfo -> Void in
    if let organization: Organizations = Organizations.organizationWithId(orgId) {
        completionBlock(false, nil)
    } else {
        self.switchOrganization(user, organization: organization, completionBlock: completionBlock)
    }
}

Users.getCurrentUserprofileWithCompletion(callback)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Aleš!  I don't know why I am having a mental block with some of this syntax in Swift.  I spent 2 years coding in Scala so none of these concepts are new to me, but I found myself just staring dumbfound at this. :/